# Forecasting - excel

Tags: excel, linear-regression, forecasting

Greetings everyone I have 5 columns : I need to forecast the consumption based on the population growth

I have 3 scenarios in the population growth : 1/ REUT
2/ IMF
3/ RETAIL

The population is going down so logically consumption should goes down.

Could you please help me with this. Below is an example of data

[image: This is my data]

Comment: have you tried the FORECAST formula?

Comment: @ScottCraner NO i tried the linear regression with LINEST but it gives me unlogic result